# Loop observable array and merge with other observable for each element

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two separate functions returning different observables.

`getCities(): Observable<City[]>`

For example `[{city: 'Amsterdam'}, {city: 'Rotterdam'}]`

`getLocations(city: string): Observable<CityLocation[]>`

For example `getLocations('Amsterdam')` will return `[{location: 'Westpoort'}, {location: 'Amsterdam-Noord' }]`

I would like to combine these two and have a function to return an observable like this:

`[
    {city: 'Amsterdam', locations:[{location: 'Westpoort'}, {location: 'Amsterdam-Noord'}]},
    {city: 'Rotterdam', locations: [{...}, {...}]}
]`

So basically the function should loop through the cities, then for each city it should get the locations and merge everything into one observable.

This is what I have now:

`getCombined() {
    return this.getCities().pipe(
      mergeMap(cities => {
        return from(cities).pipe(
          mergeMap(
            city => this.getLocations(city.city),
            (original, detail) => ({ ...original, locations: detail })
          ),
          toArray(),
          map(locations => ({ ...cities, locations }))
        );
      })
    );
  }`

But unfortunately it doesn't work and no errors in the console. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT:

Stackblitz editor: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-32wman

Comment: Create a sample on Stackblitz to give us a better idea.

Comment: OK one moment please

Comment: Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-32wman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin` for the requests and also add the locations as an array for each city, as you want per my understanding. Your modified code:

```ts
getCombined() {
  return this.getCities().pipe(
    mergeMap(cities => forkJoin(
      cities.map(c => this.getLocations(c.city).pipe(
        map(locations => {
          c.locations = locations;
          return c;
        })
      ))
    ))
  );
}
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-trsyrs?file=src/app/cities.service.ts)**

Comment: Any ideas why it's not working (getCombined() returning an empty array) when I replace the example getCities() and getLocations() functions to fetch from Firestore?

`getCities(): Observable<City[]> {
    return this.afs.collection(`cities`).valueChanges();
  }`

Above itself is working

Comment: OK I got it `.valueChanges()` observable never completes so I have to use take(1)

Comment: Cool, you figured it out yourself while I was sleeping, awesome :D